# MATLAB: adding a plot to an axis

Tags: matlab

I am using `plotyy` to plot two vectors on different y-axes. I wish to add a third vector to one of the two axes. Can someone please tell me why the following code is not working?

```
[ax h1 h2] = plotyy(1:10,10*rand(1,10),1:10,rand(1,10));
hold on; plot(ax(2),1:10,rand(1,10));
??? Error using ==> plot
Parent destroyed during line creation
```

I simply wish to add an additional vector to one of the axes (`ax(1)`,`ax(2)`) created by `plotyy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply `hold` to the axis of interest.

```
[ax h1 h2] = plotyy(1:10,10*rand(1,10),1:10,rand(1,10));
hold(ax(2), 'on'); 
plot(ax(2),1:10,rand(1,10));
```

`plotyy` works by creating two axes, one on top of the other.  You are carefully adding the new vector to the second axis.  The `hold` property is also a per-axis property, so you just need to make sure that the `hold` is set on the same axis.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize `hold` was applied to individual axes.